# I can ssh via port 42043, but not via port 7999 (connection refused)

Tags: server, ssh, firewall

I have the following setup in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host atlas
     user dci
     HostName <redacted>
     Port 42043
     AddressFamily inet
     GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

I can connect to this server via ssh, just fine:

```
▶ ssh atlas
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-88-generic x86_64)
…etc…
```

Unsurprisingly, I get the same message if I `ssh atlas -p 42043`.
However, if I try to connect via port 7999, I get the following message:

```
▶ ssh atlas -p 7999 
ssh: connect to host <redacted> port 7999: Connection refused
```

On the Ubuntu side, I ran `sudo ufw allow 7999`:

```
: ~ ; sudo ufw allow 7999
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

This changed nothing. Now, normally, I don't try to connect via port 7999 for SSH, but we do use it for git (Bitbucket).

```
▶ git pull
ssh: connect to host <redacted> port 7999: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This worked just fine until the server recently lost power and was rebooted. (We've now rebooted a couple times, including a cold reboot.) There is a post reboot script I have to run to get everything working, but I've run it, and there were no error messages reported by it. I'll also add, that while it's not that common, this server losing power has happened several times already this year, and after running this script, things usually work. (Note: I did not create this script, but I have had to modify it in the past after Bitbucket updated something. Due to the person who used to maintain the serving leaving us, I've inherited the job of fixing things on the server when things go wrong.)

Comment: Which port is ssh configured to listen on?

Comment: Per /etc/ssh/sshd_config, port 42043. It does not mention port 7999, but I'm sure this hasn't changed. The only reason I tried to ssh into it was because of the failure message from `git pull`, which was working up until the reboot.