# Unable to ssh to BitBucket server via port 7999 after Atlassian auto-update

Tags: server, ssh, git

About a week ago, the building hosting our servers briefly lost power, causing the servers to reboot. On reboot, Atlassian evidently decided to upgrade BitBucket, and it no longer works. I cannot connect to the web client (for which we use port 7990), nor can I connect via `git` (for which we use port 7999), though I can connect via `ssh` using default settings (for which we use port 42043).

Here's the relevant portion from .ssh/config:

```
Host atlas
     user dci
     HostName <redacted>
     Port 42043
     AddressFamily inet
     GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Here's the ssh results:

```
▶ ssh atlas        
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-88-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
…
```

Here's the git results:

```
▶ git pull
ssh: connect to host <redacted> port 7999: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When trying to connect to `https://<redacted>:7990/projects`, I get:

```
This site can’t be reached atlas.dependablecomputing.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Note, these errors manifested immediately after the server rebooted, and everything was working beforehand. We have a script that we have to manually run afterwards, and it initially gave error messages (see [more here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089764/i-can-ssh-via-port-42043-but-not-via-port-7999-connection-refused)), but after doing a few `chmod` commands, upgrading Ubuntu 14.04, and installing Java 8 (and rebooting/rerunning the post-reboot script after each event), all of those error messages went away. The primary problem, however (unable to to run git against the server), has remained.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Question title starts with *"Unable to ssh..."* and question body says *"...though I can connect via ssh.."*. Can you please clarify which is correct, and which tool you are using to connect to https://:7990/projects that is failing?

Comment: @TomBrossman I can connect via ssh on port 42043, but not on port 7999. We have BitBucket configured to use port 7999, which might be the default. (If you'll notice the message after the git command it starts with, "ssh: connect to host…") I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Sounds like those servers might not be running, or running with the wrong config files. Have you tried checking while connected via ssh?

Comment: @ElefantPhace — I have not. Any suggestions on how to check that? I did not set up these servers in the first place. The person who did left the company about a year ago, and things have been running fairly smoothly since then (i.e., he did a good job, but nothing lasts forever).

Comment: not familiar with bitbucket, but this might help: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/starting-and-stopping-bitbucket-server-776640144.html

Comment: Try a more verbose login with `ssh -v atlas` (you can use up to 3 `-vvv` for increasing verbosity) and see if that yields any clues. Also try `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` on the server to see what errors are shown during the failing login attempts on port 7999. Lastly, `netstat -plnt` (on the server again) will list all ports the machine is listening on and which process is listening. Do you see the sshd process listening on multiple ports? (not sure whether this is even possible...)